# File association breaks when programmatically updating ClickOnce application

Tags: clickonce

I just created a WinForms application with VisualStudio, added a file association at **Publish -> Options -> File Associations** and published it to a web location. This application has the very same update method as the one described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx. But when I publish an updated version and then run the update method from the application and perform the update, the file association disappears.

Two questions: Can you repro this? If so, is there any workaround other than not using programmatic update?

Comment: do you get a NullReferenceException doing update? See this bug in .Net 4: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/612125/updateasync-on-clickonce-deployment-with-file-associations-causes-nullreferenceexception

Comment: I was actually trying to reproduce that exception but I wonder if they "fixed" it already. BTW I'm testing on Windows 8.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Windows 8.1 and .NET 4.5.1. IS this bug really fixed? I don`t think so ... Is there any solution/workaround available?